# Set max connection retries for Selenium RemoteWebdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-remotedriver

In the setup method of our testrun we try to connect to our selenium grid. By default the connection setup is configured with 3 connection retries. I would like to change the connection retry with an option but didn't found anything in the documentation.

The following code snipped shows the connection call to the remote server:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=grid_url, desired_capabilities=d, browser_profile=None, proxy=None, keep_alive=False, file_detector=None, options=None)
```

Actually I tried to find some options in desired_capabilities but didn't found anything to configure the max retries.

How can I set the max retries?

Answer (score 0):

try using timeout like this
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#timeouts
`edge_options.timeouts()`

Comment: With the reduction of the timeouts the 3 retries will be execute much faster, but that's more a workaround than a direct solution for my issue. Is there no config param that change the maximum retries?

Comment: find nothing in the document [https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#print-page](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#print-page)